# jQuery AJAX to Rails 3, In Rails how to get the Variable Passed via Data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 app.... I have the following jQuery which is working:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/navigations/sidenav',
    data: "urlpath=" + urlpath,
    success: function(e){
        $("#sideNav-container").slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

urlpath can be paths like '/' or '/projects' or '/authors' stuff like that.

My question is how do I grab that urlpath variable in the controller so I can use it in my view to determine what sidenav to return to the user?

Thanks

Comment: Is it just? params[:urlpath] ... Anything I need to do to prevent SQL injections XSS etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the urlpath in a hash for the "data" key. Like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/navigations/sidenav',
    data:{"urlpath":urlpath},
    success: function(e){
        $("#sideNav-container").slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

This will then pass urlpath in the params object, that you can access from your controller. So you can simply do

```
params[:urlpath]
```

and you can get the urlpath you passed in. :)

Comment: Any worries about XSS SQL Injection etc with this? As it just takes a params? Also, that seems to be encoding the URL, how do I decode it in the backend Rails app?

Comment: Is the urlpath entered by the user? Also, is it encoded before it gets sent through ajax, or is it encoded once it reaches the controller?

Comment: Well it's not entered by the user but it's taken from the browser URL which a user could modifiy. A user could also post an invalid variable to try to hack the system right? Just curious if params safe guards against that or if I need to add something extra?

Comment: I was wondering if the urlpath was entered by the user to figure out where the encoding was happening. I made a sample app that passes a url through the data attribute, and it was not encoded. As for XSS, I don't believe there is any risk. How will you be determining which sidebar to render? With a simple switch or if statement that looks at the urlpath?

Comment: Ya, with an IF statement, here it is.. Thoughts? "<% if params[:urlpath] && params[:urlpath].to_s.index('/projects') == 0  %>"

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with XSS since the params[:urlpath] returns a string, and as such there is no way of its contents being 'executed'. Had you been directly passing the string into the database, then that'd be a different story.

Comment: Also, rails 3 is quite lovely and will escape html and javascript for you.