# How to make jQuery remember state in a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd be very grateful for a code snippet showing off jQuery functionality remembering state, e.g. .slideToggle().

I've read about local storage, session storage, ajax among others - what technique is preferred 2012 and how could an implementation look like in Ruby on Rails 3.2?

Comment: For clarificaions:
1. A real code example how to resolve this would be much more appreciated than general directons.
2. A simple user case could be a widget on a certain webpage in the sidebar that is foldable, so I if I hide it and leave the page - once I'm back on that page it's still hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this. To store a variable in the url as a parameter (accessible from the params[] hash in rails), in your javascript you can write something like (example taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799860/jquery-ajax-to-rails-3-in-rails-how-to-get-the-varible-passed-via-data) )

```
$.ajax({
    data:{"toggle":state}, # This stores the toggle variable in the
                           # url like so: http://localhost:3000/?toggle=1
    # Other stuff });
```

If you want something a bit more durable, try a cookie. There is a cookies[] hash in Rails3 (not sure about rails2). The session[] hash is stored as a cookie by default as well. You can check out this [railscast on making a "remember me" login function](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password) which used the cookies[] hash. Also see the [docs on the Cookie class in Rails3](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionDispatch/Cookies), which gives a pretty good explanation of the various options and methods you have available.

With jQuery, you will apparently need a plugin as the functionality to read/write cookies with jQuery is not there automatically (I was surprised to find that). Here's one on github that seems to be recommened and has some good documentation, though I haven't used it: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. I have described my final solution below.

Answer (score 2):

This episode on RC gave me nearly all information on how to solve it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

I created an ajaxed link with remote: true in the view. This link renders as well a dynamic class retrieved from a boolean value in the session.

```
<%= link_to "Click here", {action: 'retain_widget_state'}, id: "switcher", class: "#{session[:switch]}", remote: true %>
```

I added an empty action in the controller. And then in a retain_widget_state.js.erb i have the code below. In it I toggle the state in a session and then run jQuery code showing or hiding the element via a click on the link above.

```
<% session[:switch] = true if session[:switch] == nil %>
<% if session[:switch] == false %>
    <% session[:switch] = true %>
    $('.company_view').slideDown(400);
<% elsif session[:switch] == true %>
    <% session[:switch] = false %>
    $('.company_view').slideUp(400);
<% end %>
```

Wrapped in a $(document).ready(function() {}); I put the conditional code that "remembers" the state of the toggle upon a refresh of the page:

```
if ($('#switcher.true').length) {
    $('.company_view').display();
}
else if ($('#switcher.false').length) {
    $('.company_view').hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to retrieve the state at **anytime**, I would create records for the cases you want to save.  Name, value and possibly page.  Then, you can retrieve those values on page creation and use those values instead of hard-coded values.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless in itself, meaning you've got to store the data somewhere (jQuery won't "remember" anything).  Depending on your intended use, the state of the toggle field could be stored in a backend database, or stashed in a cookie on the user's browser.